# Get inner text from lxml

Tags: python, lxml

lxml.html.fromstring insists on wrapping up everything in a tag (`p` default). From this tag tree,

```html
<p>this is <b>the</b> good stuff<p>
```

I want to extract the string:

```html
this is <b>the</b> good stuff
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's often referred to as "inner xml" rather than "inner text". This is one possible way to get inner xml of an element :

```
import lxml.etree as etree
import lxml.html

html = "<p>this is <b>the</b> good stuff<p>"
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
node = tree.xpath("//p")[0]

result = node.text + ''.join(etree.tostring(e) for e in node)
print(result)
```

**output :**

```html
this is <b>the</b> good stuff
```

Comment: `strip_tags` also work in this particular case. The catch will be when there are other `<p>` tag inside the outer `<p>` and you don't want to lose the inner one.

Comment: This is great, but note that calling `node.text` will decode any htmlencoded values (e.g. turn `&nbsp;` or `&#160;` into the bytes for a non-breaking space character). At that point, there's no way to return it to its original form, because there's no way to know whether those bytes used to be `&nbsp;` or `&#160;` prior to being decoding.